# linux is not booting because error in rc.local file

Tags: linux, boot, rc.local

i make a error in /etc/rc.local file in linux so when i turn on the computer is keep on loading in ubuntu logo

[image: how to break this process]
[image: keep on loading]

Comment: Did you mean to ask a question? Like, for example, how to fix it? Have you tried booting in safe or single-user mode?

Comment: help me to fix this

Comment: Boot some other system from USB stick, mount the disk that contains rootfs of your installed OS and edit the file

Comment: An error in `/etc/rc.local/` should not cause the system to not boot. An error message would be displayed and the boot would continue. I think you have something else going on other than `command not found`. As @ArkadiuszDrabczyk said, boot from a live cd and edit the script.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), especially not badly-cropped images taken at an angle...

Comment: @ilkkachu his system does not boot, it's not easy to get its text as text, at least not without some sort of OCR. Your comment is not really appropriate in this case. We ask people not to post images of text when they can copy/paste text. This is not the case.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, they could still type it, though yes, I'll admit that's a chore. But the least to do would be to take a clear picture and crop it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `init=/bin/bash` as a kernel boot option.
2. Boot.
3. `vi /etc/rc.local` (nano, joe, mcedit, whatever), edit and save.
4. `sync`
5. `mount -o remount,ro /`
6. `reboot`

Notes:

- The commands above may need full paths, e.g. `/bin/vi` or `/usr/bin/vi`. Alternatively you could run `export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin`.
- The `reboot` command may not work. In this case you could reboot using `Alt + SysRQ + R` or pressing the physical reboot button on your case.

Comment: sir , Pass means i want to press pass key

Comment: My English was correct but given the fact that you have troubles understanding it I replaced the word "Pass" with "Add". From https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.19/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html : *The kernel parses parameters from the kernel command line up to “--“; if it doesn’t recognize a parameter and it doesn’t contain a ‘.’, the parameter gets **passed** to init: parameters with ‘=’ go into init’s environment, others are **passed** as command line arguments to init. Everything after “--” is **passed** as an argument to init.*

Comment: sir where i want to add this init=/bin/bash

Comment: The first hit in Google: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters I'm sorry, I'm not free tech support, this is my last message here.

Comment: GRUB menu not showing sir for me

Comment: The first hit on Google, https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time